# accessing localized strings in javascript function using jquery-localize

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization

I am using jquery-localize plugin for my static web project. I can localize strings in html file, like this:

```
<p rel=localize[hello]></p>
```

But I also need to use localized strings in js functions. 
How can I correctly access those jquery-localize strings from a function?

```
alert( localized_strings[hello] ??? );
```

here is the jquery-localize plugin:  https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize/blob/master/README.markdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've no experience with this plugin, but after a look at the code, I believe you can access the data of the loaded package through

```
$.localize.data.PACKAGE.KEY
```

where `PACKAGE` is the language package you've loaded via

```
$("[data-localize]").localize("PACKAGE");
```

and `KEY` is the whatever key you want to retrieve (in your example `hello`).

Since the package is loaded via AJAX you might have to ensure that the data is actually available when you need it. The plugin seems to define a callback method for when the data is loaded an expose it through an option. So you could do something like this:

```
$("[data-localize]").localize("PACKAGE", { 
    callback: function(data, defaultCallback) {
        console.log(data.KEY); // <-- do whatever here
        defaultCallback(data);
}});
```